# Python NLTK not taking out punctuations correctly

Tags: python, nltk, punctuation

I have defined the following code

```
exclude = set(string.punctuation)
lmtzr = nltk.stem.wordnet.WordNetLemmatizer()

wordList= ['"the']
answer = [lmtzr.lemmatize(word.lower()) for word in list(set(wordList)-exclude)]
print answer
```

I have previously printed exclude and the quotation mark " is part of it. I expected answer to be [the]. However, when I printed answer, it shows up as ['"the']. I'm not entirely sure why it's not taking out the punctuation correctly. Would I need to check each character individually instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a set from `wordList` it stores the string `'"the'` as the only element,

```
>>> set(wordList)
set(['"the'])
```

So using set difference will return the same set,

```
>>> set(wordList) - set(string.punctuation)
set(['"the'])
```

If you want to just remove punctuation you probably want something like,

```
>>> [word.translate(None, string.punctuation) for word in wordList]
['the']
```

Here I'm using the [`translate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.translate) method of strings, only passing in a second argument specifying which characters to remove.

You can then perform the lemmatization on the new list.

Comment: if I just do answer = [lmtzr.lemmatize(word.lower()) for word in wordList word.translate(None, string.punctuation)] I get an syntax error...

Comment: @Carrie `newlst = [word.translate(None, string.punctuation) for word in wordList]` `answer = [lmtzr.lemmatize(word.lower()) for word in newlst]`